# why do i have a type error when i run this loop to print out key value pairs? each item k and v are str already

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

getting an error when I try to run the code.

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 10, in
> >     
> >         print(k+':'+v)
> >     TypeError: must be str, not list

```
with open("a_movie.json") as json_file:
    json_data=json.load(json_file)

# Print each key-value pair in json_data
for k, v in json_data.items():
    print(type(k))
    print(type(v))
    print(k+':'+v)
```

sample json:

```
 {'Title': 'The Social Network', 'Year': '2010', 'Rated': 'PG-13', 'Released': '01 Oct 2010', 'Runtime': '120 min', 'Genre': 'Biography, Drama', 'Director': 'David Fincher', 'Writer': 'Aaron Sorkin (screenplay), Ben Mezrich (book)', 'Actors': 'Jesse Eisenberg, Rooney Mara, Bryan Barter, Dustin Fitzsimons', 'Plot': 'As Harvard student Mark Zuckerberg creates the social networking site that would become known as Facebook, he is sued by the twins who claimed he stole their idea, and by the co-founder who was later squeezed out of the business.', 'Language': 'English, French', 'Country': 'USA', 'Awards': 'Won 3 Oscars. Another 171 wins & 183 nominations.', 'Poster': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGUyZDUxZjEtMmIzMC00MzlmLTg4MGItZWJmMzBhZjE0Mjc1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg', 'Ratings': [{'Source': 'Internet Movie Database', 'Value': '7.7/10'}, {'Source': 'Rotten Tomatoes', 'Value': '96%'}, {'Source': 'Metacritic', 'Value': '95/100'}], 'Metascore': '95', 'imdbRating': '7.7', 'imdbVotes': '590,040', 'imdbID': 'tt1285016', 'Type': 'movie', 'DVD': '11 Jan 2011', 'BoxOffice': '$96,400,000', 'Production': 'Columbia Pictures', 'Website': 'N/A', 'Response': 'True'}
```

Comment: Is your v a list?

Comment: Paste a sample of your JSON. I think it has `list` as values which is causing the error.

Comment: try to print(k, ":", v) ?

Comment: The error says that they're not strings, but lists.

Comment: attached my json .   v is a str  ? eg. 'The Social Network' is a string from the 'Title' key

Comment: thanks guys i think i just spotted the issue thanks to Mayur .  one of the  key:value pairs has a list in the values, whilst all the rest are str

Comment: btw your `json` is not. It looks more like you printed a `dict`.

Comment: Please post an mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("a_movie.json") as json_file:
    json_data=json.load(json_file)

# Print each key-value pair in json_data
for k, v in json_data.items():
    print(type(k))
    print(type(v))
    print(k,':',v)
```

Not every time k and v be str. So instead of **+** use **,**

Comment: and if the OP doesn't want spaces as it appears they're trying to do with the str concat, then maybe: `print(k, ':', v, sep='')`

Comment: thanks all.. one of the key:value pairs has a list in the values, whilst all the remaining pairs  are str. didnt notice that!

Answer (score 1):

```
print(k+':'+v)
```

the error is from there because your v is a list. Here is an alternative:

```
f = [str(z) for z in v]
x = ",".join(f)
print(k+":"+x)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment ; not sure what im seeing wrong here in my code and the json.  v is a str ? eg. 'The Social Network' is a string from the 'Title' key